# How do I use findOneAndUpdate in mongoose properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've read all the similar questions in here, and they don't work. I'm trying to update a model called Transaction, and I'm using findOneAndUpdate to update it. There is no errors, but the doc simply returns null.
Code:

```
app.post("/transaction/update", isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
const username = "dennis"
const count = req.body.count
const date = req.body.date
const change = req.body.change
const service = req.body.service
const expires = req.body.expires

const transaction = await Transaction.findOneAndUpdate({ "username": "dennis" }, {
    $set: {
        "count": count,
        "date": date,
        "change": change,
        "service": service,
        "expires": expires
    }
}, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    console.log(doc)
})
await transaction.save()
res.redirect("/admin")
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
app.post("/transaction/update", isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
const username = "dennis"
const count = req.body.count
const date = req.body.date
const change = req.body.change
const service = req.body.service
const expires = req.body.expires

const transaction = await Transaction.findOneAndUpdate({ "username": "dennis" }, 
      { 
       "count": count,
       "date": date,
       "change": change,
       "service": service,
       "expires": expires,
      }, { new: true })

res.redirect("/admin")
})
```

You don't have to use `$set` or call `.save()`.

Reference: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introduction-to-mongoose-for-mongodb-d2a7aa593c57/#update-record